# Saving belongsTo (without hasmany)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to save a record (using ember-data) with a `belongsTo` relationship to itself

```
App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  parent: DS.belongsTo(App.Account)
});
```

When loading the record from the server, the relationship is loaded correctly. However when I try to save the record (create or update), the belongsTo record isn't updated. I'm trying to set it explicitly:

```
a.set('parent', b);  (where a and b are both valid App.Account records)
```

having a look at the data sent over the wire, the `belongsTo` attribute isn't sent.  What am I doing wrong? am I able to set the `belongsTo` relationship without specifying a `hasMany` relationship?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to specify `belongsTo` without `hasMany`. At least it always worked fine for me. When you talk about "having a look at the data sent over the wire", are you saving the parent or the child?

Comment: I'm saving the child. The parent doesn't explicitly know about the child (no hasmany).

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you running and what adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm running beta2 with the restadapter.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember Data Beta 2 you will need to change `DS.belongsTo(App.Account)` to `DS.belongsTo('account')`.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem. The `belongsTo` fields isn't saved at all. It doesn't save within ember, nor does it persist to the server.

Comment: Hm. Not sure then. Can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm running ember-app-kit and i'm unsure how to get the exact setup to work with fiddle. But i'll give it a go

Comment: Are you running a Rails backend?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've been able to tell, Ember doesn't assume that the parent key is stored on the child in a `belongsTo` situation, instead it assumes that the parent keeps a list of all children.  (Yeah, it's weird...)  I've been able to work around it by also setting up `parentId : DS.attr('number')` and then manually populating the `parentId`.  Less than ideal, but it does work.

Comment: With that arrangement, how do you get the belongsTo to persist? Does just having the parentId magically do the job?

Comment: That largely depends on which Adapter you're using, and how your server handles things.  In my app (using the RESTAdapter) the `parentId` property is actually stored on the child objects in the DB, so when I set `parentId` and save the child object, then the server saves that id to the DB.  If I need to immediately show the child being added to the parent I use `pushObject` to get the child into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as more info on the problem. I'm fighting a similar battle, and what I've found in my case is that when serialization happens the `parent` property is a `DS.PromiseObject`--this in itself wouldn't be a problem, but at the time serialization is happening it isn't `isSettled`…therefore, the Ember Data serialization process picks up `undefined`. The property *is* settled before and after the save, so I'm thinking that the fact that the parent object is being saved also and is refreshing its relationships (or something) is causing the child's `parent` property to become unsettled, leading to the problem.

Another part of this puzzle is that the Ember Data serializers actually serialize to a Javascript *object*, so you internally have an object like this: `{ "parent": undefined }`, but when that object gets serialized to a *string* (likely by the browser's `toJSON` implementation?) the `parent` property gets dropped entirely--and that's what you see go across the wire. And I'm guessing that's why @Jeremy is observing what he's observing.

Now I just have to figure out how to fix it. Anyone???